# What is this condition trying to compare?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently learning python and encountered this function.

```
def min(root, min_t): # min_t is the initially the value of root
    if not root:
        return min_t

    if root.key < min_t:
        min_t = root.key

    min_t = min(root.left, min_t)
    min_t = min(root.right, min_t)

    return min_t
```

I'm quite confused to what it means by "if not root". What condition is it trying to give? if "root" is not what? What comparison is "if" trying to make?

UPDATE: Root is a binary tree which has the subtrees self.left and self.right. In can also be None. This is the case if the node is a leaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python language reference on [boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) explains this:

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are
>   used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted
>   as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty
>   strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists,
>   dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted
>   as true. (See the `__nonzero__()` special method for a way to change this.)

In your case, since `root` seems to be an instance of a user-defined type (it has `left` and `right` members, which no built-in type has), it either has the `__nonzero__` method implemented, or `None` or a similar "empty" object is passed in to signal that there is no "left" and "right".

Answer (score 3):

In python, you dont necessarily have to compare something to something else.

`if root` checks, by default, if the variable root has a content, or if it is an empty variable. 
Let me explain you via examples:

```
if ""
if 0
if None
if []
if {}
if ()
```

would all return False

While any other values would return True.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `if expr:` really means `if bool(expr):`, i.e. it evaluates whatever expression is given to it then converts the result to a boolean (in many cases, of course, it's *already* a boolean, e.g. `x > y` will be `True` or `False`*).

The built-in types have [rules for boolean evaluation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing); in short, empty containers and sequences (`dict`, `list`, `tuple`, `set`, `str`, etc.) plus zero numerical values (`0`, `0.0`, `0j`, etc.) and `None` evaluate `False`-y, anything else is considered `True`-y. User-implemented types usually follow this convention.

This lets `if root` be a handy shortcut for e.g. `if root != 0` or `if len(root) > 0`, depending on what type of object `root` is expected to be. Note that `None` is usually, per [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations), tested with `if name is not None`; this lets you easily distinguish between `None` and other `False`-y values.

* *Unless the "magic methods" are implemented in a non-standard way*